# Embed version number in content type used for many libraries?

Tags: 2013, content-type, versioning

I'm using SharePoint 2013. This guide http://rayamondo.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/sp-version-to-word-template/ shows how to embed the version number in a content type for a specific document library.

My problem is that I need to be able to use the same content type for multiple document libraries and be able to store the template somewhere central so that changes can easily be made to it. Using the technique above a change made to the central document will remove the label from the template.

Are there any workarounds for this or alternative solutions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This solution is rather old and for Sharepoint 2007. Is there anyway to do this for sharepoint 2011 also?